# ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd

Tags: python, ssl, import, executable, py2exe

I've tried to create an exe file using py2exe. I've recently updated Python from 2.7.7 to 2.7.10 to be able to work with `requests` - `proxies`.

Before the update everything worked fine but now, the exe file recently created, raising this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "puoka_2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mLib
  File "mLib.pyc", line 4, in <module>
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 94, in <module
  File "httplib.pyc", line 71, in <module
  File "socket.pyc", line 68, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd
```

It could be probably repaired by changing `options` in setup.py file but I can't figure out what I have to write there. I've tried `options = {'py2exe': {'packages': ['requests','urllib2']}})` but with no success.

It works as a Python script but not as an exe.

Do anybody knows what to do?

EDIT:

I've tried to put into `setup.py` file this import: `from _ssl import RAND_egd`
and it says that it can't be imported.

EDIT2: Setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
# from _ssl import RAND_egd
setup(
  console=['puoka_2.py'],
  options = {'py2exe': {'packages': ['requests']}})
```

Comment: This seems to be an error that occurs only with python 2.7.10. I had this error and downgrading to python 2.7.9 solved it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Google, it seems to be a very rare Error. I don't know exactly what is wrong but I found a **workaround** for that so if somebody experiences this problem, maybe this answer helps.

Go to `socket.py` file and search for `RAND_egd`. There is a block of code (67th line in my case):

```
from _ssl import SSLError as sslerror
from _ssl import \
     RAND_add, \
     RAND_status, \
     SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, \
     SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, \
     SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, \
     SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP, \
     SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, \
     SSL_ERROR_SSL, \
     SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT, \
     SSL_ERROR_EOF, \
     SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE
try:
    from _ssl import RAND_egd
except ImportError:
    # LibreSSL does not provide RAND_egd
    pass
```

Everything what you have to do is to comment the 5 lines:

```
  #try:
        #from _ssl import RAND_egd
  #except ImportError:
        ## LibreSSL does not provide RAND_egd
        #pass
```

I don't know why it raises the `ImportError` because there is a `try - except` block with `pass` so the error should not being raised but it helped me to successfully run the `exe` file.

EDIT: WARNING: I don't know whether it could cause some problems. I experienced no problems yet.

Comment: Faced error while running executable generated with py2exe. Did the step as mentioned, generated executable and was working. Went back and uncommented the lines, tried to reproduce this error and couldn't. :D

Comment: @JamesJithin So Steve Guo (another answer) is probably True. Maybe it is enough to change anything. :)

Comment: Faced while trying to launch [Google Cloud SDK 's app-engine-python dev_appserver.py](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-serve)

Answer (score 3):

Experienced the same problem.

Solved the problem by removing directories 'dist' and 'build' created by py2exe when it was run on previous version of Python.

Seems like py2exe doesn't rebuild all the files every time. And obviously doesn't catch the fact of Python version changing.

Finally you have a mix of files generated with different versions of Python in your 'dist' directory.

My setup.py is pretty simple:

> from distutils.core import setup import py2exe
>
> setup(console=['xxxxxx.py'])

Comment: Confirming this worked for me. You can also rename the dist and build folders if you're at all concerned.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was in two installations of Python27: x86 and x64. Only x86 version was in %PATH%, but pip installation script was using files from x64 installation for some reason. Solution was: remove x64, cause I don't really need it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it. This might be caused by old version of socket.pyc.

My solutions is edit socket.py, add a space to anywhere and delete then. And then run your setup.py again which will generate new socket.pyc.

Now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just remove socket.pyc under c:\Python27\lib, and run py2exe again. The error gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the python version from 2.7.12 to 2.7.9 and problem gone.

It will replace the python files but leave you packages as it is.

Good Luck.