# ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl

Here is the error I am receiving when I try to run my Google App Engine site locally. It actually works on my old computer (windows 10 and python 2.7.6 was installed) but not on a new one I just got with windows 10 and Python 2.7.11 installed. Any ideas on how to fix?

```
from _ssl import RAND_add, RAND_egd, RAND_status, SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP, SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, SSL_ERROR_SSL, SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT, SSL_ERROR_EOF, SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE

ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to get RAND\_egd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195175/where-to-get-rand-egd)

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to also install some OS-specific library, probably the local equivalent of `ssl`, see [Using Runtime-Provided Libraries with the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#local-libraries)