# Fetch firebase user info from AppEngine application

Tags: python-2.7, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, webapp2

We are testing with Firebase Authentication, and we're checking out [python SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).
Attempting a simple get user operation from our Firebase users results in the following error:

```
TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",))
```

We tested from local server then from a staging GAE URL, as our initial thoughts were that maybe communicating with Firebase *requires* that the request comes from an Https URL. But, in both cases, we saw the same error. It's probably something else then.

Code used extract:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate("custom/conf/conf.json")
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

user_uid = '901234753'
user = auth.get_user(user_uid)
print 'Successfully fetched user data: {0}'.format(user.uid)
```

Any clue what may have caused this error and how to resolve it?

---

**Update 1:**

Adding SSL in app.yaml as suggested by @Mihail Russu in his comment

```
- name: ssl
version: latest
```

generated a new error: `ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd`

in line:

```
from _ssl import RAND_add, RAND_egd, RAND_status, SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE,,SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE
```

As per the page ["ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762371/importerror-cannot-import-name-rand-egd) and the page ["Fix RAND_egd import error in SDK..."](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900282) I edited socket.py located at /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine (on Mac) to match their suggestions:

```
from _ssl import \
    RAND_add, \
    RAND_status, \
    SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, \
    SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, \
    SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, \
    SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP, \
    SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, \
    SSL_ERROR_SSL, \
    SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT, \
    SSL_ERROR_EOF, \
    SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE
try:
    from _ssl import RAND_egd
except ImportError:
    # LibreSSL does not provide RAND_egd
    pass
```

**Update 1 result:**

New errors generated:

-> local dev server: `('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))`

-> GAE: `('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(100 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(100 bytes read))`

Anyone had a successful implementation of Firebase Auth with GAE? This feels a bit like going down the rabbit hole, thought using the SDK would be as easy as the javascript version of firebase auth..

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AppEngine Standard Environment, make sure you have the following in your `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

> App Engine supports the native Python SSL library for the Python 2.7 runtime via the SSL library, **which you must add to your app**.

See more at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/ssl_support

Comment: I read through the link provided, but I am not sure why SSL library is required if GAE already supports HTTPS and certificates can be issued for example via LetsEncrypt.
Moreover, adding `- name: ssl version: latest` introduces a new error:
`from _ssl import RAND_add, RAND_egd, RAND_status, SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE,...,SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE`
`ImportError: cannot import name RAND_egd`
Would you happen to know why is all this required in the first place? is there a way around this? Other APIs we deal with don't need any of this!

Comment: `I am not sure why SSL library is required if GAE already supports HTTPS and certificates can be issued for example via LetsEncrypt` - AppEngine's frontend takes care of https certificates, not your app. For your app to be able to create & handle outgoing https connections an ssl library is required, most (all?) of which are written C which means you cannot simply include them with your app (as only pure python modules are allowed) so Google came up with a small list of whitelisted C libraries which can be included via `app.yaml`'s `libraries` section.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2 & resolution**

Following on the errors resulted from **update 1** found:

1. The page [TransportError when running within App Engine](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/46#issuecomment-313566026) which mentions a
   workaround for the same error `('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))`.
2. And this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581465/1394228) for
   the error `('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(80 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(80 bytes read))` which also appeared later.

**The answer from Mihail and the above pages had finally made it possible to use firebase auth to fetch user form Firebase Auth Users**

For reference, the final code snippets would be:

**app.yaml :**

```
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

**appengine_config.py :**

```
# appengine_config.py
import os
import google
import imp
import inspect

from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')

# whitelists the socket and ssl libraries for the dev app server, and uses the system-level socket library instead of the one packaged with the App Engine SDK. Your mileage may vary.    
if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Development'):
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox
    sandbox._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += ['_ssl', '_socket']

    runtime_path = os.path.realpath(inspect.getsourcefile(inspect))
    runtime_dir = os.path.dirname(runtime_path)

    # Patch and reload the socket module implementation.
    system_socket = os.path.join(runtime_dir, 'socket.py')
    imp.load_source('socket', system_socket)

    # Patch and reload the ssl module implementation.
    system_ssl = os.path.join(runtime_dir, 'ssl.py')
    imp.load_source('ssl', system_ssl)
```

**socket.py :**

```
from _ssl import \
    RAND_add, \
    RAND_status, \
    SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, \
    SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, \
    SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE, \
    SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP, \
    SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, \
    SSL_ERROR_SSL, \
    SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT, \
    SSL_ERROR_EOF, \
    SSL_ERROR_INVALID_ERROR_CODE
try:
    from _ssl import RAND_egd
except ImportError:
    # LibreSSL does not provide RAND_egd
    pass
```

**code :**

```
# firebase
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials

# handle requests for GAE
import requests
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine

requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()

# initialize firebase
cred = credentials.Certificate("custom/conf/conf.json")
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

user_uid = '901234753'
user = auth.get_user(user_uid)
print 'Successfully fetched user data: {0}'.format(user.uid)
```

---

I did get a couple of warning though that I need to check out later:

```
AppEnginePlatformWarning: urllib3 is using URLFetch on Google App 
Engine sandbox instead of sockets. To use sockets directly instead of 
URLFetch see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.contrib.html.AppEnginePlatformWarning)

WARNING  2018-03-26 00:33:31,894 urlfetch_stub.py:534] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length']
WARNING  2018-03-26 00:33:33,079 urlfetch_stub.py:534] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length']
```